# How to apply aspectj for different project in workspace

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Good day.

Please help me apply aspectj jar to a project from my Eclipse workspace. Is it possible to do so?? thank you. I use LTW aspectj approach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add it as a library. You can add Libraries to a project in many different ways. [Here is a listing of your options.](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)